# IE doesn't show all images

Tags: php, html, css, image, internet-explorer

I got this webpage which shows several brand logos.

I noticed that Google Chrome and Firefox have no trouble, but IE doesn't show all my pictures.

Even when I go to the direct link of the images IE doesn't open certain pics while Google Chrome or FireFox do open those.

Following picture can't be opened by IE but opens in Chrome/FireFox:

http://juniorsteps.mediaspex.be/sites/default/files/logos/develab.jpg

I can't figure out why this is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your image is a [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) JPG, which IE can't read.

Use Photoshop or a similar tool to change the colour spectrum. A free tool that can re-save the JPG as RGB is [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Comment: Is there a way to this using php.

Comment: @Stephan not easily, no. The GD library can't read CMYK JPGs. You would have to use [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org)

Comment: The content manager of the website should be able to add the logo's of the brands and he probably doesn't know photoshop.
He uploads them using a form I wrote in php/drupal

Comment: @Stephan I added a link to a free tool, maybe that helps